# Remove known value parameters from the query string

Tags: php, regex

I am using PHP scripting.

I have an URL like http://example.com?tag=test1&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B07BH2N15X&linkCode=df0&ascsubtag=test2. In the query string, tag=test1 and ascsubtag=test2, I know the values test1 & test2 not the key. Now I want to remove the keys tag & ascsubtag from the URL for sensitization purpose.

Expected output is http://example.com?creative=165953&creativeASIN=B07BH2N15X&linkCode=df0. How can I achieve this in simple way.

I have tried the following code,

```
$a = parse_url("http://example.com?tag=test1&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B07BH2N15X&linkCode=df0&ascsubtag=test2");
parse_str($a['query'], $queryStr);
$interchanged = array_flip($queryStr);
unset($interchanged['test1']);
unset($interchanged['test2']);
echo $a['scheme'] . "://" . $a['host'] . (isset($pURL['path']) ? $pURL['path'] : '') . "?" . http_build_query(array_flip($interchanged));
```

Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: look into `parse_str` and `http_build_query`

Comment: What do you mean by *knew the values test1 & test2* - do you always want to remove these fields (`tag` and `ascsubtag`) or is it based on values?

Comment: @iArcadia: I have tried, parse_str('querystring', $qrystng) and interchange the key values of the array and unset the keys test1 & test2. After that build query from the array using http_build_query. Want to know the better way.

Comment: @NigelRen: It is based on the values. I don't know which key will come for these values.

Comment: The problem with setting the value as the key and then unsetting those particular ones is what if two fields have the same value - one will be lost.

Comment: Also best if you can add your existing code to the question as it helps others see your efforts.

Comment: @Saravanan: Did you get your solution or still looking for it?

Comment: @NigelRen: I have update my question with code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simpler solution (IMHO and more maintainable) is to use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) to remove any of the values yo don't want in your original code rather than the flip/unset/flip method...

```
$a = parse_url("http://example.com?tag=test1&creative=165953&creativeASIN=B07BH2N15X&linkCode=df0&ascsubtag=test2");
parse_str($a['query'], $queryStr);
$interchanged = array_filter($queryStr, function($value) { return ( $value != "test1" && $value != "test2");});
echo $a['scheme'] . "://" . $a['host'] . (isset($pURL['path']) ? $pURL['path'] : '') . "?" . http_build_query($interchanged);
```

Comment: Hope we can do this in single line using regex replace. Which one is the better?

Comment: Depends what you mean by better?  A single line solution isn't a useful metric if the number of possible things you want to remove increases - how maintainable is it?  What if you need this to work with POST variables.  There isn't an easy which is better answer IMHO.